# what resistor i should use for programming pickit3?

Tags: resistors, pickit

I'm trying to program a 16f877a pic with the pickit3 and I'm be able to find what resistor i should use for MCLR to Vdd Pull-Up because it doesn't say clearly and i don't either what compiler either 8x,16x, or 32x please tell me this please because in my tutorial that I'm following doesn't say anything about this

Answer (score 1):

The PIC10, PIC12, PIC12 and PIC18 are all 8bit-MCUs, so you need an 8bit compiler like XC8.

And for the pullup, something like 10-100k is fine.

**EDIT:**

When developing a board for an MCU, you should always have a look into the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582b.pdf)
This one has over 230 pages, but you don't to read everything. I'd say, most important are device overview (pinout), various subsections of "special features" (14) and of course the periphals you are planning to use.
The datasheet also contains (pseudo) schematics which help to understand how things work.

Section 14.4 (PDF page 150) shows this external wiring for MCLR:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp46ZE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 and R1 are used as filter, and are not essentially necessary in this case. However, it's always good to follow the suggestions of the datasheet.

R2 is the pullup resistor. It's recommended to be >1kOhm, but can be much higher. I prefer 10-100kOhm, since if th programmer powers the board with 5V, it already has to source 5mA on VDD and sink 5mA on MCLR when 1kOhm is used.